# HttpException (0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net

Unable to use SQL Server because either ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server, or ASP.NET does not have permission to run the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure. If the ASP.NET Session State schema has not been installed, please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above. If the schema has been installed, please grant execute permission on the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure to either the ASP.NET application pool identity, or the Sql Server user specified in the sqlConnectionString attribute

Answer (score 1):

changed `sessionState` from `sessionState mode="SQLServer"`  to `sessionState mode="InProc"` in web.config

Now it working fine for me.